# How to integrate iAD without a xib file

Tags: xib, declaration, subview, nib, iad

I have an app that does not use any form of storyboard or xib or nib. I have used iAD before but it involved dragging on and declaring in the code. How do I make the banner add view a subview, (my knowledge of such programming is poor, I have just started objective-c). Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [admob mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/mediation/)... its sooooo easy to implement

3 lines of code and you're done